# How to change jquery .toggle() to use display:table-cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am using jquery .toggle() to show a div on a page that has display:none on page load. However, under the default settings jquery inserts display:block, where I would want display:table-cell. How can I achieve this? My attempt so far:

```
<div class="mydiv" style"display:none">test</div>

.mydiv {
display:table-cell;
}

$("a#showdiv").click(function() {
    $(".mydiv").toggle();
```

Comment: You could toggle a class name that changes it between the `display: none` and `display: table-cell`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead and use css for the styling..

**html**

```
<div class="mydiv table-hidden">test</div>
```

**css**

```
.mydiv {
    display:table-cell;
}
.mydiv.table-hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$("a#showdiv").click(function() {
    $(".mydiv").toggleClass('table-hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS for the styling *@Gaby aka G. Petrioli* or use the `.css()` method in jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydiv">test</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a#showdiv").click(function() {
    if($(".mydiv").css("display") == "none"){
      $(".mydiv").css("display", "table-cell");
    } else {
      $(".mydiv").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work already.

In jQuery, unless the style attribute of the element has `display` initially set to something else other than `none`, when the `show` is called, all it does is remove the style attribute for display. It doesn't set it block.

You can see for yourself in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh97q/) that when the button is clicked, the `display` that is set in the CSS is what the element is set to.

Here's the relevant code in the [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L56):

```
function showHide( elements, show ) {
    var display, elem, hidden,
        values = [],
        index = 0,
        length = elements.length;

    for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
        elem = elements[ index ];
        if ( !elem.style ) {
            continue;
        }

        values[ index ] = data_priv.get( elem, "olddisplay" );
        display = elem.style.display;
        if ( show ) {
            // Reset the inline display of this element to learn if it is
            // being hidden by cascaded rules or not
            if ( !values[ index ] && display === "none" ) {
                elem.style.display = "";
            }

            // Set elements which have been overridden with display: none
            // in a stylesheet to whatever the default browser style is
            // for such an element
            if ( elem.style.display === "" && isHidden( elem ) ) {
                values[ index ] = data_priv.access( elem, "olddisplay", css_defaultDisplay(elem.nodeName) );
            }
        } else {

            if ( !values[ index ] ) {
                hidden = isHidden( elem );

                if ( display && display !== "none" || !hidden ) {
                    data_priv.set( elem, "olddisplay", hidden ? display : jQuery.css(elem, "display") );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the display of most of the elements in a second loop
    // to avoid the constant reflow
    for ( index = 0; index < length; index++ ) {
        elem = elements[ index ];
        if ( !elem.style ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( !show || elem.style.display === "none" || elem.style.display === "" ) {
            elem.style.display = show ? values[ index ] || "" : "none";
        }
    }

    return elements;
}
```

I should note that toggling classes will usually be faster in general because there is less information to check.

Comment: Just for posterity: jQuery does restore the initial display setting, but if there are multiple definitions @media, it does NOT restore the one used by the device/browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
div.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

<button id="showdiv">Show/Hide</button>
<div class="mydiv display-none">test</div>
<div class="mydiv display-none">test</div>
<div class="mydiv display-none">test</div>
<div class="mydiv display-none">test</div>

$("#showdiv").click(function() {
    $(".mydiv").toggleClass('display-table-cell');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7q27y/

If you understand CSS precedence as well, you don't technically "need" the `div.` on the latter:

```
div.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7q27y/

Of course, this is due to it's *precedence* and the fact it falls *after* the other statement, which both would calculate as the same precedence otherwise. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/7q27y/2/